# "Cannot be disproven" e.g. solipsism is ______

Tags: single-word-requests

Single word that means something cannot be disproven?

In the same way unprovable means that something cannot be proven.

E.g. solipsism would be able to be described with this, because it's perfectly logical and *infallible*.

A synonym of this word may be infallible, but infallible is too strong. Infallible connotes too strongly "absolute."

Solipsism is undisprovable.

Comment: You seem to have worked your way into a logical muddle: Some statement is  provable or not provable. An argument is fallacious and people are fallible. One would use the negative: an argument is disprovable or an argument in not disprovable. Undisprovable sounds, and is, indisputably awful.

Comment: 'untestable'?. Did you look in a thesaurus around all these?

Comment: It's just tricky because while these are all correct ways of describing things like this, e.g. untestable, I want a word that connotes "is logically true but not necessarily true"

Comment: Are we looking for something simpler, like “axiom”?

Comment: Uh… what did your favourite dictionaries, thesauruses and search engines not tell you, please? Never you mind no solipsism; the term for something which cannot be disproven would be *undisprovable*, would it not?

Comment: If you want *disprovable* in the word, I would go with *non-disprovable*. I think @Mitch has it right, because [*falsifiability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) requires *testability*.

Comment: @theonlygusti logically true is usually considered identical to necessarily true with respect to any context. So you can't have one without the other. And now we move into either philosophy or math. You could say 'irrefutable' because it is something that is not refutable but it is also not provable which is usually not what is meant by 'irrefutable'. On the math side, you can say that solipsism is undecidable (it is neither provable nor disprovable from given data). But that is a technical use of 'undecidable' so may not work for your audience.

Comment: [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Examples_of_undecidable_statements)

Answer (score 7):

[Unfalsifiable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfalsifiable) might work:

> not capable of being proved false
>
> *(definition from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfalsifiable))*

Answer (score 1):

Non-disprovable (used in logic discussions) or undisprovable (as per http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disprovable) seems acceptable.

As indicated in the comments, it refers to specific situations where a hypothesis cannot be tested or in general cannot be disproven by any scientific method, etc.